# JPA Query table by date and state SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to pull data from two tables bookings table and routes table. Bookings table contains a foreign key route_id. What I want to do is spool from bookings table but also get the departure time and departure date from the routes table based on the foreign key which is a primary key on the routes table.

I tried the following :

```
@Entity
public class bookings {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Nullable
private String email;

private String amount;

private String phoneId;

private Timestamp dateCreated;

private int state;
/* Bokkings state will have 3 states 1 => pending, 2 => booked and 3 => used*/

@ManyToOne
private routes routes;
}
```

The routes entity :

```
@Entity
public class routes {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@ManyToOne
private busStations busStations;

private String destination;

private String price;

private String departureTime; // So same routes but different depature times

private Date departureDate; // So same routes but different depature dates

private Timestamp dateCreated;

@Nullable
private String dateModified;
}
```

I put the following in my Crud Repo Interface

```
    public interface bookingsRepository extends CrudRepository<bookings, 
Integer> {

    List<bookings> findByRoutesDepartureDateAndState(Date date, int state);
}
```

The issue I have is I can not pull the values from the tables with the Query I wrote in my Crud Interface. I know the query is wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see how the `Bookings` table and the `Routes` table are connected with one another. `Bookings` has a `ManyToOne` relationship to `Routes` but I do no see the inverse relation of this. Also avoid using primitives for the `state`. You could very well use the `@Enumerated` annotation to map to an enum. Finally, you're not describing the problem you have.

Comment: @Aris I have stated my problem, which is I am not getting the data I want to pull from the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use interface with findByStateAndRoutesDepartureDate(int state, Date departureDate) method name...
Anyway I think that use JPA Specification is a better way to implement this kind of query.

Comment: Nope. Your solution did not work. I think first of I have major problem in defining the relationships and then piling the data